# C# : how to use x64 and x86 libraries on same project

Tags: c#, .net, dll

i have a C# project and some 2 different libraries: one of them is x86 (awesomium) and another x64.
When i run the project i get error because of assembly difference.
Isn't it possible to use x86 and x64 libraries on same project?

Comment: A 64 bit process can only load 64 bit DLLs, a 32 bit process can only load 32 bit DLLs.

Comment: @twa No, they will not. Because of an emulation layer (WOW64), 64-bit versions of Windows can run 32-bit applications, but that does *not* mean that 32-bit libraries can be loaded into 64-bit projects (or vice versa).

Comment: @Cody Thank you for the info, I didn't know that I will edit the comment.